# change the values of an array from nan to zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array A on python that has some nan values created by numpy.nan. I want to set all the nan values to zero using `A[A==numpy.nan] = 0`. It doesn't change the array at all. Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want [`np.isnan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html):

```
A[np.isnan(A)] = 0
```

The problem with your code is that (according to IEEE), `nan` doesn't equal anything -- even itself.

As a side note, there's also

- `np.isinf` -> (+/- infinity)
- `np.isfinite` -> (not infinity or NaN)
- `np.isposinf` -> (+ infinity)
- `np.isneginf` -> (- infinity)

Comment: Shouldn't `np.isfinite` say "*not* infinity or NaN"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the numpy function to change all the nan value at matrix x to zero.

```
numpy.nan_to_num(x)
```